# Building Hash from Array of Hashes

Tags: ruby

I'm new to Ruby and trying to solve a problem. I have an array of hashes:

```
list = [{"amount"=>2.25,"rel_id"=>1103, "date"=>"2012-12-21"},
 {"amount"=>2.75,"rel_id"=>1103, "date"=>"2012-12-24"},
 {"amount"=>2.85,"rel_id"=>666, "date"=>"2012-12-27"},
 {"amount"=>3.15,"rel_id"=>666, "date"=>"2012-12-28"}
 #and many many more..
]
```

I need to group them by rel_id, that i could see total amount and dates they were given, in this kind of format:

```
{1103=>{:total_amount=>5.0, :dates=>["2012-12-21", "2012-12-24"]}, 666=>{:total_amount=>6.0, :dates=>["2012-12-27", "2012-12-28"]}}
```

I solved this in this way, but i'm pretty sure it's one of the worst approach to do that and i think it's not a ruby way..

```
results = {}

list.each do |line|
 if !(results.has_key?(line["rel_id"]))
 results[line["rel_id"]]={:total_amount=>line["amount"],:dates=>[line["date"]]}
 else
 results[line["rel_id"]][:total_amount] = results[line["rel_id"]][:total_amount]+line["amount"]
 results[line["rel_id"]][:dates]<<line["date"]
 end
end
```

Maybe you could give me or explain how to implement a nicer, more beautiful approach in a ruby way?

Answer (score 5):

You can do something like this:

```
list.each_with_object({}) do |details, rollup|
  rollup[details["rel_id"]] ||= { total_amount: 0, dates: [] }
  rollup[details["rel_id"]][:total_amount] += details["amount"]
  rollup[details["rel_id"]][:dates] << details["date"]
end
```

Edited for readability/names.

Comment: out of curiosity what does the ||= do?

Comment: @Tall Paul, If the value for the key is nil, e.g. it doesn't exist, ||= sets the hash key to the value on the right.  Almost the same as: `hash[key] = 0 if hash[key].nil? `  Testing for nil is actually more precise because both the values nil and false will cause ||= to set the value for the key.

Comment: canonical imperative solution, +1. I'd just give more meaningful names to variables (and a space after a comma).

Comment: @Babai, It can be improved further. Fewer lines doesn't always mean most efficient.

Comment: @7stud: `r[h["rel_id"]]` will never be `false`, why are you worried about it?

Answer (score 1):

Functional approach (I'll use `mash`, use `Hash[...]` if no Facets):

```
purchases_grouped = list.group_by { |p| p["rel_id"] }
result = purchases_grouped.mash do |rel_id, purchases|
  total_amount = purchases.map { |p| p["amount"] }.reduce(:+)
  dates = purchases.map { |p| p["date"] }
  accumulated = {total_amount: total_amount, dates: dates}
  [rel_id, accumulated]
end
#=> {1103=>{:total_amount=>5.0, :dates=>["2012-12-21", "2012-12-24"]}, 
#    666 =>{:total_amount=>6.0, :dates=>["2012-12-27", "2012-12-28"]}}
```

Comment: This is not much elegant... sorry.. :( @alex one is very clear.. `each_with_object` is good one for this problem.. I think..

Comment: @Babai: How would you write it in functional style?

Comment: As soon as you chose group_by, you weren't going to have the best solution.  Too many traversals of the data.  The data can be accumulated in one pass.

Comment: I like a functional approach, you don't know what the best solution is until you run it with a large data set.

Comment: @7stud: First I write functional solutions with no inplace updates. If I see this particular snippet is slowing my app, then I write some imperative hack, but not before. No doubt this is slower than using a `each`.

Answer (score 1):

```
h = list.group_by{|h| h["rel_id"]}
h.each{|k, v| h[k] = {
  total_amount: v.inject(0){|x, h| x + h["amount"]},
  dates: v.map{|h| h["date"]},
}}

h # => ...
```

Or

```
h = list.group_by{|h| h["rel_id"]}
h.each{|k, v| h[k] = {
  total_amount: v.map{|h| h["amount"]}.inject(:+),
  dates: v.map{|h| h["date"]},
}}

h # => ...
```

Comment: I did some benchmarking with your first solution. It was surprisingly fast.

Answer (score 0):

```
list = [
 {amount: 2.25, rel_id: 1103, date: "2012-12-21"},
 {amount: 2.75, rel_id: 1103, date: "2012-12-24"},
 {amount: 2.85, rel_id: 666, date: "2012-12-27"},
 {amount: 3.15, rel_id: 666, date: "2012-12-28"},
]

results = Hash.new do |hash, key| 
  hash[key] = {}
end

list.each do |hash|
  totals = results[hash[:rel_id]]

  totals[:amount] ||= 0
  totals[:amount] += hash[:amount]

  totals[:dates] ||= []
  totals[:dates] << hash[:date]
end

p results

--output:--
{1103=>{:amount=>5.0, :dates=>["2012-12-21", "2012-12-24"]}, 
 666=>{:amount=>6.0, :dates=>["2012-12-27", "2012-12-28"]}}
```

Alex Peachey's  each_with_object solution modified:

```
results =  list.each_with_object({}) do |h, acc|
  record = acc[h["rel_id"]] 
  record ||= { total_amount: 0, dates: [] }
  record[:total_amount] += h["amount"]
  record[:dates] << h["date"]
end
```